# How does Hybris get the label of the attributes in Backoffice?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

label (java.lang.String): Key for the localized column name. The value is looked up in the localization bundles. If this string is blank, the column is named according to @qualifier.

For example type="AbstractOrder" in *-backoffice-config.xml:

```
<editorArea:tab name="hmc.properties"> 
...
  <editorArea:section name="hmc.common"> 
    <editorArea:attribute qualifier="name"/> 
    <editorArea:attribute qualifier="description"/> 
    <editorArea:attribute qualifier="expirationTime"/> 
  </editorArea:section> 
...
</editorArea:tab>
```

So, How do label attributes get from the database? I don't undestand. I tried reviewing two tables

> ATTRIBUTEDESCRIPTORS

and

> ATTRIBUTEDESCRIPTORSLP

But still not clear about it?
For example the label for the Product's code attribute can be found and modified for English language in core-locales_en.properties
As you noted above. However, I still see the config value stored in the Database when you change the value. When I delete this value in the config file.Then ant clean all -> start server ->[ hac -> Platform -> Update. (check only "Localize types")]. Although the value in the config file was deleted but the label did not change (It is similar to the value in the database).So can say: Label value is configured in the config file. But if not found in the config file it will look in the Database. I think so.But I still do not understand the mechanism of its implementation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has same answer with your last question. Labels are provided by properties files. Check resource folder in your backoffice extension.

Comment: As you noted above. However, I still see the config value stored in the Database when you change the value. When I delete this value in the config file.Then ant clean all -> start server ->[ hac -> Platform -> Update. (check only "Localize types")]. Although the value in the config file was deleted but the label did not change (It is similar to the value in the database).So can say: Label value is configured in the config file. But if not found in the config file it will look in the Database. I think so.But I still do not understand the mechanism of its implementation...

Comment: hybris giving pk for every type on own ORM. When you make localize types, it updates ORM system. ORM system save its configuration to DB and use. If you want to use db translation you can override LabelService and i18nService.

Comment: "When you make localize types, it updates ORM system. ORM system save its configuration to DB and use". But I still do not understand the mechanism of its implementation. Can you show me the code in the core of Hybris? Thanks you...

Comment: Can you say more about this? Thanks mkysoft.

Comment: You can check de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ModelService for creating, removing or changing attributes of item (model). I haven't got class name for updating ORM tables. May be you can find code which are updating maptypes table.

Comment: Thanks you so much.